# NSNumberFormatter confused about minus?

Tags: nsnumberformatter

Check this out:

```
(lldb) po NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("+10.6")
nil
(lldb) po NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("10.6")
▿ Optional(10.6)
(lldb) po NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("-10.6")
▿ Optional(-10.6)
```

So apparently, adding a minus sign to a number is perfectly valid, but a plus sign is not. Is this expected behaviour, and it so, anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say why NSNumberFormatter doesn't tolerate the "+" sign but Swift's Float type seems to be smarter:

```
 Float("10.6")    --> 10.6
 Float("+10.6")   --> 10.6
 Float("-10.6")   --> -10.6
 Float("Garbage") --> nil
```

It doesn't return an NSNumber but I guess you could always type cast/convert it.

Comment: Ahhh, that seems like a perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

[The problem is that no locale uses a positive prefix by default in their number formatters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14149740/how-do-i-force-a-sign-character-on-the-output-of-an-nsnumberformatter).

You need to explicitly tell your `NSNumberFormatter` instance what to do.

This works in Xcode playground:

```
import Foundation

// this outputs "nil"
let bustedNnumber = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("+10.6")

// this outputs "-10.6"
let minusnumber = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString("-10.6")

let nf = NSNumberFormatter()
nf.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
nf.positivePrefix = "+"

// this outputs "10.6"
let positiveNumber = nf.numberFromString("+10.6")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that means that `let enum = nf.numberFromString("10.6")` returns nil, so it's not a universal solution unless I'm missing something.